# How to keep track of elements generated in random?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have 3 buttons and random sounds are played when the mouse is close to one of these buttons.

```
var audio_1 = new Audio("1.mp3");
var audio_2 = new Audio("2.mp3");
var audio_3 = new Audio("3.mp3");

var array_son_video = new Array(audio_1, audio_2, audio_3);
```

The function to play when the mouse is close to an element :

```
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
    $('#mouse_position').html("mouse position: x=" + e.pageX + "; y=" + e.pageY);
    if (e.pageX > 300 && e.pageX < 400) {
        var random_number = Math.floor ( Math.random() * 2 );
        son_bt_video_1 = array_son_video[random_number];
        son_bt_video_1.play();
        $("#son_bt_video_1").text('son random : '+random_number);
    }
});
```

This part works but i see it's not clean :

1) A random number is generated each time the mouse moves. I only need to generate one when the sounds is finished.
2) Also, i need to keep track of the sound in order to verify if it is paused :

```
if (son_bt_video_1.paused) {
    // generate a new sound
}
```

Like this :

```
if (e.pageX > 300 && e.pageX < 400) {
    if (son_bt_video_1.paused) {
        var random_number = Math.floor ( Math.random() * 2 );
        son_bt_video_1 = array_son_video[random_number];
        son_bt_video_1.play();
        $("#son_bt_video_1").text('son random : '+random_number);
    }
}
```

As the sounds are generated in random, i don't know how to keep track of them. Can you advise me ?

EDIT :

The user has no control (no play and pause buttons). When the mouse is close to a button, the sound is simply played. When playing is finished, the user can play again if his mouse is close to the button.

This code works with no random :

```
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
    if (e.pageX > 300 && e.pageX < 485) {               
    son_bt_video_1 = array_son_video[0];
    son_bt_video_1.play();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sébastien, you mention and test for `paused` but you don't give the code which causes the paused state to occur.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot In fact, there is no pause. I just want to check if the file if finished playing. I guess that if the sound is paused, it is not playing.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I've edited my question with more infos and a code with no random which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sébastien,

I have never used `new Audio()` but assuming it works the same as an HTML5 `<audio>` element, then something along the following lines should work :

```
var tracks = [
    new Audio("1.mp3"),
    new Audio("2.mp3"),
    new Audio("3.mp3")
];
tracks.current = null;

$('body').mousemove(function(e){
    if(!tracks.current || tracks.current.ended) {
        $('#mouse_position').html("mouse position: x=" + e.pageX + "; y=" + e.pageY);
        if (e.pageX > 300 && e.pageX < 400) {
            var random_number = Math.min(tracks.length-1, Math.floor ( Math.random() * tracks.length ));
            tracks.current = tracks[random_number];
            tracks.current.play();
            $("#son_bt_video_1").text(['son random : (' , random_number, ') ', tracks.current.src].join(''));
        }
    }
});
```